# No output file even though variables are not empty

Tags: javascript, node.js

Even though I can clearly see my output in console. I can't write them into a file. There is 1 output file and its undefined-03-02-2017.txt which contains single line '15:33 undefined'.

```
for (i = 0; i < channelcount; i++) {
    messages[i] -= messagesOld[i];
    console.log(channels[i] + ' ' + messages[i]);
    messages[i] = messagesOld[i];

    fs.open('logs/' + channels[i] + '.txt', 'r', function (err, fd) {
        if (err && err.code == 'ENOENT') {
            fs.writeFile('logs/' + channels[i] + '-' + moment().format('MM-DD-YYYY') + '.txt', moment().format('H:mm') + ' ' + messages[i], function (err) { });
        } else {
            fs.appendFile('logs/' + channels[i] + '-' + moment().format('MM-DD-YYYY') + '.txt', moment().format('H:mm') + ' ' + messages[i] + '\n', function () { });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why does your channels[i] return undefined? Or was the file undefined-03-02-2017.txt  not made by this function? PS: for the record, appendFIle will also create a file if it doesn't exist, so your if statement is redundant.

Comment: Thats what I can not understand. I can see them in console as output.

Comment: Ah ofc, it;s async one moment.

Comment: infamous for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fs.open()` is an async function. So your entire loop will run before the first callback actually gets called. By that time i equals channelCOount + 1 and channels[ channelCount + 1 ] is undefined.

You can either wrap the callback into a closure, use a `let` if you can use ES6, or use `fs.openSync()`

Answer (score 0):

@Pyro, you used writeFile incorrectly. Please see syntax
writeFile(file, data[, options], callback)

you have to use like this

fs.writeFile('logs/' + channels[i] + '-' + moment().format('MM-DD-YYYY') +  moment().format('H:mm') + '.txt ' , messages[i], function (err) { });

Comment: What did you change to the syntax?

Comment: @Shilly I mean he didn't concatenate filepath properly.

Comment: I wanted to keep H:mm in text file as well as my message variable.

Comment: oh sorry my fault....